# Combinatorial Number System

Tags: combinatorics, number-systems

I recently read up Combinatorial Number System. I wanted to know how would we find the nth combination when arranged in lexicographic manner and when **"repetition was allowed".**
Eg:
{1,2,3}
the 6th combination is {1,3}
({1},{2},{3},{1,1},{1,2},{1,3})

Comment: can you be more elaborate...what do u mean by rank combination...

Comment: @AbishankaSaha, I have edited the question. Get it, now?

Comment: Are you assuming that each set is listed in non-decreasing order? If so, you’re really looking at finite sequences rather than at sets.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am assuming that each set is listed in non-decreasing or lexicographic order. But how does that reduce it to finite sequences?

Comment: In effect you’re identifying each multiset with the unique non-decreasing sequence of its elements and then listing these sequences in [shortlex order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, yes. But when I meant find the 6th combination of {1,2,3}, it meant directly getting the answer as {1,3} without having precomputed the previous combinations and having ordered them. According to CNS I think this is possible when repetitions are not allowed, but I am not able to extend it to cases where repetition are allowed.

Comment: I understood that you wanted a direct calculation; I was just making sure that I understood the order that you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing here is like a basis of numeration in $n+1$ with each number containing at least one $0$ missing.